# How to compile source files from library path automatically without generating .o, .a neither .so files?

Tags: c++, arduino, g++, simulator

I'm trying to compile a `main.cpp` file, which has some third-party libraries (some build by me), but I can't leave the `.o`, `.a` or `.so` files in the source directories.

My tests and searches lead me to a weirdo solution, where I should include every `.cpp` file into `g++` command line.

`./main$ g++ -o test.run -I./../src ./../src/*.cpp main.cpp`

I'd found something about using `-L` option of `g++` compiler,  but as I understand it, it only works with static archive libraries (`.a`) or shared objects (`.so`).

As long as those libraries are supposed to be used as Arduino libraries, I don't think I should leave those files in their directories, and also, I don't want to go there end recompile every time some minor change is made.

There is any way to compile these files without manually adding each `.cpp` file? Considering that maybe not all file must be included (because my final goal is to build a simulator). Maybe something like:

`./main$ g++ -o test.run -I./../src -L./../src/ main.cpp`

Also, any tips on which compilation tags might be useful in this case?

---

PS.: I can handle with recompiling at every change, with `make` it's ok, but since I'm going to use some preprocessor directives, I don't  feel comfortable with it, cuz sometimes it must be ready to run in arduino, sometimes in PC;

PPS.: My final goal is to build an [arduino simple port and software simulator](https://github.com/UFABCRocketDesign/Simulator/commit/8fd92c7b4318d374db3161867dd095b21813fb6b), which is already working, and that's the main reason of I'm afraid to let those additional files there, the libraries must keep compiling at arduino, and must stay in the arduino include path.

---

My test directory tree is:

```
.
├── main
│   └── main.cpp
└── src
    ├── source.cpp
    └── source.h
```

`main.cpp` file content:

```cpp
#include <source.h>

int main()
{
    Just one;
    return 0;
}
```

`source.h` file content:

```cpp
#ifndef _SOURCE_H
#define _SOURCE_H

#include <iostream>

class Just
{
public:
    Just();
};

#endif
```

`souce.cpp` file content:

```cpp
#include "source.h"

Just::Just()
{
    std::cout << "It Works!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Would it be preferable to dump the output into a bin folder? `g++ blab blah blah -o ../bin/file.o` It's still there so you don't have to build everything every freaking time but it's out of the way. If you want it gone, delete the bin directory. Build automation tools are pretty good at this stuff.

Comment: Why don't you want the compiler generated intermediate files to stick around?  What problem would not having them solve?  You could always just delete them as part of your build process.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Arduino compiler will ignore these temporary files, anyway, recompiling and then deleting every time, to make sure they do not get in the way, it seems misfortune.@1201ProgramAlarm